# issues inserting a div from Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a div with some text before another div in the document.
Here's my script in a nutshell, assume init() gets called when onload page:

```
       <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function init () {
                       var div = document.createElement('div').className = 'title';
                       div.innerHTML = 'Hello';
                       var reference = document.getElementById('content');
                       document.body.insertBefore(div, reference );            
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content">blah blah</div>
            <br /><br />
        </body>
```

I get a **type mismatch error** on document.body.insertBefore(div, reference), Can someone please let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your assignment of `div` will leave the value of that variable as the string "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function init () {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.className = 'title';
     div.innerHTML = 'Hello';
     var reference = document.getElementById('content');
     document.body.insertBefore(div, reference );            
}
```

You were setting the div to the string title I think (never checked)

Yep here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/FxFzc/